# soql to find data modified in last 1 hour

Tags: salesforce, soql

i am using salesforce SOQL to find the data that was modified in last 1 hour using the below query

```
SELECT name FROM Lead WHERE  LastModifiedDate = TODAY AND HOUR_IN_DAY(LastModifiedDate) > 1
```

this does not work reliably though. I have seen some solutions where it expects to create a custom formula field and then use it to query. Is it possible to do by just fixing the above query?

Answer (score 1):

you can find the Leads that were modified in the last hour like so:

```
DateTime dt = System.Now().addHours(-1);
List<Account> accLst = [SELECT Name FROM Lead WHERE Lead.LastModifiedDate>=:dt];
```

You can check this article to understand more - [How to get modified records in the last hour using SOQL](https://www.salesforce-tricks.com/soql/how-to-get-modified-records-in-the-last-hour-using-soql/)

Comment: what is System here? remember i am making rest calls so the date on where this code executes could be different than what is on salesforce server. it depends on the timezone servers are deployed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by System, This is Apex code, you can parameter in your API for a date, to pass the date you want from the server you want

Comment: I am not using apex

Comment: Perfect, It is working for me. Thanks @ayoubelmoudni